# Cannot use existng Time Machine Backup on OS X Server after changing password

Tags: time-machine, backup, password, osx-server

I'm backing up to a drive attached to an OS X Server via the Time Machine backup service. Recently I changed my password on OS X Server I had been authenticating with for the backup.

So, I had to remove the old drive and connect to the server backup location again, authenticating with my new password. However, it doesn't appear the my laptop is recognizing there is an existing backup because it shows "Latest backup: None". in Time Machine preferences after selecting the backup disk.

I don't want to start my backups over. Is there anyway I can continue backing up to my existing server backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I had to delete the old password from the login / system key chain before it would let me connect again to my server.

Also, Time Machine won't show you the old backups until after it makes the first new backup, so you might need to clear the old password and then set up the destination again and then wait for the backup to finish.

At that point, the interface should show the old range. If it doesn't inherit the old backups, you have options, but there are some steps needed to get there first possibly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not having issues connecting to the server with the new password. If I perform a new backup, are you saying I should then be able to somehow select the old backup bundle (assuming it is not overwritten)?

Comment: I'm saying the system is designed to reuse the old sparse bundle. Have you completed one backup after reconnecting? You don't _do_ anything but wait - there is no selection needed other than the server itself.

Comment: I have not completed a new backup yet because I'm afraid it will overwrite my existing bundle. Are you saying it will perform a full backup, using the old bundle, and after that is done it will show me my past backups when entering time machine, rather than overwriting (deleting and recreating) my existing bundle?

Comment: yes - that's how it works unless something breaks. The unless is rare and you can see that and stop the backup if needed... You will not lose the old backups - worst case is it forks - the mac would have "two" sets of backups one starting now.

Comment: After the first backup completed, I was above to Enter Time Machine and browse the old backups. Thanks for your help! :)